# Usage of the word "commuted"?

Tags: ambiguity, connotation

The word **commuted** has multiple meanings (the arcane one being) - reduction in a judicial sentence.
Heretofore, I thought it only meant **travelled** (from one place to the other).

I am looking for examples of the word "commuted" being used in different sentences which give an understanding of each of its meaning.

Comment: The question as written is too broad: it can generate too many answers. Please try checking a good dictionary and then edit the question to ask specifically about what still confuses you.

Comment: <http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commute#English>

Answer (score 2):

The word **commute** in the sense of "travelling to and from work" actually has the same origin as the other senses of the word. *Commute* broadly means "to change to something less severe", so a death sentence is **commuted** to life imprisonment.

The usage of *commute* to mean *travel* goes back to the 1840s:

> The term “commute” derives from its original meaning of “to change to
>   another less severe.” In the eighteen-forties, the men who rode the
>   railways each day from newly established suburbs to work in the cities
>   did so at a reduced rate. The railroad, in other words, commuted their
>   fares, in exchange for reliable ridership (as it still does, if you
>   consider the monthly pass). In time, the commuted became commuters. In
>   New York, and in cities like Philadelphia, Boston, and Chicago,
>   railways begat reachable and desirable suburbs, so that, by the time
>   the automobile came along, patterns of development, and a calculus of
>   class and status, had already been established. -- [**There and Back Again, New Yorker, April 16, 2007**](http://www.newyorker.com/reporting/2007/04/16/070416fa_fact_paumgarten?currentPage=all)

From [**etymonline.com**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=commute&allowed_in_frame=0):

> Sense of "go back and forth to work" is 1889, from commutation ticket
>   "season pass" (on a railroad, streetcar line, etc.), from commute in
>   its sense of "to change one kind of payment into another"

A traveller would buy a *commutation ticket* - one which was *commuted* from a higher to a lower price. As they *commuted* their tickets, so they became **commuters**. Once cars were invented, the term *commuter* came to mean anyone who travels regularly.

Answer (score 1):

The word **commute** can be used as both a noun and a verb. I'll write out a few sentences using the word and explain its definition in each case.

> The death sentence was commuted to life imprisonment.

In this case, commute is used in the judicial sense. The penalty is reduced to a less severe one. Commute is used as a transitive verb.

> Robin Sparkles commuted to the mall.

Here, Robin Sparkles travels to the mall. Commute is used as an intransitive verb.

> Alchemists were once said to be able to commute basic metals to gold.

In this sentence, commute means to substitute. It is an intransitive verb.

> The commute to work every morning is a joyous experience.

Finally, commute is used as the act or instance of commuting. It's used as a noun.

See the [definition of commute](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commute).